# Count words in Pandas Column, store top X in a New Column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a DF like this:

```
Doc_ID         Text 
  1            hi hi hi 
  2            hello hello1 hello 
  3            hey hallo
```

I want to count the words in the Text column, and store that in a new column, called (topXwords). 
The desired output:

```
Doc_ID         Text                topXwords  
  1            hi hi hi            hi:3
  2            hello hello1 hello  hello:2, hello1:1
  3            hey hallo           hey:1, hallo:1
```

**What have I tried?**

I tried to convert the text column into a list:

```
df["topXwords"] = df["Text"].str.split()
```

And after that, I tried to loop over the list, and count all the items in the list. For 1 list it works, but it is not possible to store it as a new column:

```
import collections
df["topXwords1"]= collections.Counter(df["topXwords"])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


This fails, but it works in this example: 

xxx = ["a","a","b"]
counter = collections.Counter(xxx)
counter
Out[43]: Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
```

**I used counter, because it worked in a single example. Ideally, I want to adjust the number of top keywords. **

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'hi hi hi'],
        [2, 'hello hello1 hello'],
        [3, 'hey hallo']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Doc_ID', 'Text'])

print(df.Text.str.split().apply(Counter))
```

**Output**

```
0                    {'hi': 3}
1    {'hello': 2, 'hello1': 1}
2       {'hey': 1, 'hallo': 1}
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

If you want to include only the top x words, do the following (in this example x=1):

```
df['topXwords'] = df.Text.str.split().apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Doc_ID                Text     topXwords
0       1            hi hi hi     [(hi, 3)]
1       2  hello hello1 hello  [(hello, 2)]
2       3           hey hallo    [(hey, 1)]
```

Comment: Might be worth including an alternative here with `most_common` using a lambda for longer strings

Answer (score 1):

With `pd.Series.value_counts` feature:

```
In [333]: df["topXwords"] = df.Text.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s.split()).value_counts().to_dict())

In [334]: df
Out[334]: 
   Doc_ID                Text                  topXwords
0       1            hi hi hi                  {'hi': 3}
1       2  hello hello1 hello  {'hello': 2, 'hello1': 1}
2       3           hey hallo     {'hallo': 1, 'hey': 1}
```